# Glassfish 4.1 high CPU usage

Tags: java, glassfish, cpu, cpu-usage, glassfish-4

I have an issue running GlassFish 4.1 (Java 8 update 20, Windows server 2008).

As soon as application usage goes up, one of the cores goes to maximum load and stays that way even after all clients are gone. Only GlassFish restart helps.

It seems to me it is the acceptor thread (currently using only one). I tested with two acceptor threads and as a result two of the cores went full load.

Similar problem here: [Glassfish 4 Grizzly Threads Heavy CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922809/glassfish-4-grizzly-threads-heavy-cpu-usage).

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I stopped using Glassfish and switched to Payara, its more stable and preconfigured for production; you should probably try it

Comment: Looks like same. I start Glassfish 4.1.1 from Netbeans and it get 100% load of 1/2 cores on 2 phisical cores (hyperthreading)

Comment: How many threads are there in the "http-thread-pool"? If there are not enough threads to service requests then the SelectRunner can appear to "spin"